# Trouble capturing data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bulleted list and each list item has a data attribute for country. I want to get the data attribute of the active list item and do stuff with it. For now, I am just trying to alert it back in a message. However, the alert message I'm getting says [object Object].

Here is the HTML list:

```
<ul class="country_list">
 <li class="country_name france" data-country="fr">&nbsp;</li>
 <li class="country_name united-states active" data-country="us">&nbsp;</li>
 <li class="country_name china" data-country="cn">&nbsp;</li>
 <li class="country_name spain" data-country="es">&nbsp;</li>
 <li class="country_name italy" data-country="it">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

This is the javascript I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$("li.country_name").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var cc = $(".active").data("country");
    var countryMessage = $("your country is " + cc + "!");
    alert(countryMessage);
});
});
```

I'm very new to Javascript and jQuery and have been trying to sort this out most of the day, but nothing has worked. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: try `var cc = $(this).data("country"); alert('Country = ' + cc);` You want the data from the instance of `li.country`

Comment: That works! Thank you so much. I tried several variations using $(this), but obviously was doing something wrong. :)

Comment: So just to clarify what was happening, this `var countryMessage = $("your country is " + cc + "!");` attempts to find the element matching `"your country is " + cc + "!"`, and returns a jquery object (with no results). If you simply remove the $ function call surrounding your string, it would work fine. 

_Tl;dr: you don't need to call jQuery on everything._

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation @Blexen! It helps to understand what I'm doing wrong, so I can improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified your code in [codepen](http://codepen.io/gwokae/pen/DBfvs) . Please also check the comment :D

```
$(function(){ 
    // this function will execute when document.ready
    var $li = $("li.country_name").click(function(){
        $li.removeClass("active") // you can cache all li items, it's not necessarily query all the time
        var cc = $(this).addClass("active").data("country");
        alert("your country is " + cc + "!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for showing the optimized code. It's really helpful to see this improved version with the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
var cc = $(".active").attr("date-country");
```

You may even do

```
var cc = $(this).attr("date-country");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try: Demo here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhwebxu/4t72h7s6/1/)

```
    var $ul=$('.country_list'),
        cssClassActive='active',

        // show message
        showMsg=function(country){
          var countryMessage='your country is'+country;
          alert(countryMessage);
        },

        // handler
        handler=function(){
          var $this=$(this);
          if($this.hasClass(cssClassActive)){
              $this.removeClass(cssClassActive);
          }
          $this.addClass(cssClassActive);
          showMsg($this.data('country'));
       };

   // delegate event
   $ul.delegate('li','click',handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
use .attr('data-country') instead of data('country')
```